# What is the client app supposed to do with the JWT obtained via OpenID Connect?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect

I have a scenario where OIDC seems like a good fit: a mobile app where users to need to fetch some private data from a server. I've read OIDC tutorials [such as this one](http://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect), and I think I understood them, but there's still a crucial final "hole" in the global picture.

Anyway, if I understood OIDC's Code Flow correctly, this is a brief summary of the interactions:

1. The mobile app will contact the OIP authorization endpoint, indicating in the `scope` that we're interested in the user's email.  It will provide as `redirect_uri` a pointer to a simple web server running in the mobile app itself.
2. The OIP will contact the mobile app's via the `redirect_uri`, and provide it with an authorization code.
3. The mobile app will now contact the OIP token endpoint and provide it with the authorization code obtained in step 2. It will also provide the OIP with a `redirect_uri` where the reply must be sent.
4. The OIP will contact the app's via the `redirect_uri`, and provide it with a signed JWT with the claim (email) we requested.

And this is where the tutorials end.  I presume that it's now implied that the mobile app will send the JWT obtained in step 4 to my server.  However, how is the server supposed to know that the JWT is valid?  Sure, it is signed by the OIP, but is the server supposed to have a hardcoded list of OIP public keys to validate the JWT?  These last crucial steps seem to be missing from the OIDC tutorials I found...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenID Authorization Code flow] is slightly different in point 4. Once the authorization token is obtained, the client requests the token ID to the token endpoint, which **returns a response that includes an ID Token, without redirection** (request must include `redirect_uri` param and server will ensure that is identical to the original)

This is the full [OpenID Authorization code flow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps)

> 1. Client prepares an Authentication Request containing the desired
>      request parameters.
> 2. Client sends the request to the Authorization
>      Server.
> 3. Authorization Server Authenticates the End-User.
> 4. Authorization Server obtains End-User Consent/Authorization.
> 5. Authorization Server sends the End-User back to the Client with an Authorization Code.
> 6. Client requests a response using the Authorization Code at the Token Endpoint.
> 7. Client receives a response that contains an ID Token and Access Token in the response body.
> 8. Client validates the ID token and retrieves the End-User's Subject   Identifier.

Finally the client must validate the token according **[3.1.3.4 ID Token Validation](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation)**. A summary of the important points would be:

- `iss` contains the issuer identifier and `aud` your `client_id`
- current time between `iat` and `exp`
- **Validate signature of the tokens** using the keys provided by the Issuer. In this flow, TLS server validation may be used to validate the issuer in place of checking the token signature. In case of HMAC, `client_secret`of client_id is used as key to validate
- Validate `nonce`, `azp` or `azr` is requested

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the correction regarding point 4.  However, you did not address my actual question: after the mobile app validates the token and sends it to my server, how is the server supposed to trust it?

Comment: You have to validate the token signature using the public key provided by the server (or the secret if using HMAC), and then check the content of some claims. Validation can be done in client or server side. Usually signature validation is done in server side to avoid distribution of the keys to clients. If signature is correct you can trust that the token has been issued by the Issuer and it has not been altered. Also note that if you retrieve the token with a TLS trusted connection, then validation of signature may be omitted